# I need to reuse stock quote data that I am pulling from external JSON

Tags: json

I have created a stock quote using this...

```
function quote_search(json) {
  var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol_span");
  var last = document.getElementById("last_span");
  var exchange = document.getElementById("exchange_span");
  var change = document.getElementById("change_span");

  symbol.innerHTML = json.symbol;
  last.innerHTML = json.last;
  exchange.innerHTML = json.exchange;
  change.innerHTML = json.change;
}
```

And it is populating this table...

```
<table id="stock-data">
  <tr>
    <td id="symbol_span"></td>
    <td id="last_span"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="exchange_span"></td>
    <td id="change_span"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to reuse that same data on two other stock quotes. Is there a way I can do this? Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is my updated code that works thanks to Degenerate...

```
var stockData;

function quote_search(json) {

  window.stockData = json;

  var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol_span");
  var last = document.getElementById("last_span");
  var exchange = document.getElementById("exchange_span");
  var change = document.getElementById("change_span");

  symbol.innerHTML = json.symbol;
  last.innerHTML = json.last;
  exchange.innerHTML = json.exchange;
  change.innerHTML = json.change;

  symbol3.innerHTML = window.stockData.symbol;
  exchange3.innerHTML = window.stockData.exchange;
  change3.innerHTML = window.stockData.change;
}
```

Comment: So you want to reuse the `json` variable outside the `quote_search` function? Declare a public variable outside the function with `var yourGlobalVariable;` and then inside the function set it using `window.yourGlobalVariable = json;`. Now you can re-access the data using `window.yourGlobalVariable` (ex: `exchange2.innerHTML = window.yourGlobalVariable.exchange;`).

Comment: I used a public variable outside of my function `var stockData;`. Then inside the function I set it equal to the json `window.stockData = json`. I then created a new function `function useData(stockData)` and basically reused the code from my original function but instead used `exchange2.innerHTML = window.stockData.exchange;` But it didn't populate the quote. I must be missing something.

Comment: So what’s the problem then? Feed it to other functions that extract whatever else data you need in the same way … (Or make it _one_ function with an additional parameter that tells it what info to extract, and call that multiple time.)

Comment: Yeah I would make it one function. You need to show your other code if you want more help because we don't know what you are trying to populate.

Comment: Degenerate, your answer did the trick. I have updated the post above to show what made it work.